É ideal fazer a alocação dentro de uma função?
Olá, estou trabalhando num projeto em C e dentro dele utilizo algumas funções genéricas que fazem alocação dentro de uma função para utilizar fora dela, aqui está alguns exemplos:
void *alocarPonteiro(int numElementos, size_t tamanhoElemento) {
    void *ponteiro = malloc(numElementos * tamanhoElemento);

    if (!ponteiro) {
        printf("Erro ao tentar alocar memória.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ponteiro;
}

char* lerRespostaString(char *mensagem) {
    char strAux[200], *str;

    printf("%s", mensagem);
    gets(strAux); // Sei que usar 'gets' não é ideal
    str = alocarPonteiro((strlen(strAux) + 1), sizeof(char);
    strcpy(str, strAux);
    __fpurge(stdin);

    return str;
}

É ideal eu fazer a alocação de ponteiros dentro de outras funções ou isso pode causar problemas?

Esta pergunta já foi postada, melhorias devem ser feitas editando a pergunta original. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
